# Issue with the sessions on android mobile devices and browsers

Tags: php, android, session, mobile, browser

I discovered recently that my web site is not running well when I open it on android mobile phone browser (chrome for example). The issue is the following one:

I have a session set at the begining of each page like this:

```
session_name ("mysite");
session_set_cookie_params (0,"/","mysite.com",true, true);    
session_start();
```

And I'm trying from "page1.php" to execute script on "page2.php" and get back some data.

"page2.php" firstly need to check for the inputs from the current user session with this code

```
$_SESSION['cart']['number_of_items']
```

and based on it to make some calculations and send the result back to "page1.php".

**This process works fine since many years without any problems on different PCs also on some mobile devices**, but now I see it does not return any results... :(

Trying to isolate the problem I understood that even I set session name, each time when I access the "page2.php" result for the current session ID is different and this is what I beleive the reason to fail on calculations and final result.

Here is the log what I got from

```
session_id()
```

1. "page1.php" open session and store some data under $_SESSION['cart']['number_of_items'] ->
   session ID returned by this page is "xxxx1"
2. "page1.php" try to execute script on "page2.php" -> session ID returned by this page is "xxxx2"
3. "page1.php" try to execute same script on "page2.php" -> session ID returned now by this page is "xxxx3"
4. "page1.php" try to execute again same script on "page2.php" -> session ID returned now by this page is "xxxx4"
5. etc. each time session ID returned is different

and I can not access to the correct data from for current session. To repeat same code executed on PC works as expected.

Could you please help me to understand what is wrong with advise how to fix this problem?

Many thanks in advance,
Cheers!

Comment: Have you seen/used: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/issues/

Comment: I found a way to make it work adding this line after session_start():
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+3600);

I do not fully understand how this solved the problem, but it works. My worry now is how safe is to store session ID in cookie ?